# Не правильная ширина и высота создаваемого через javascript окна

Tags: javascript, html, объекты

Путь к изображению приходится получать из стиля элемента, поэтому создаю обьект `Image`. При первом открытии всё работает корректно, ширина и высота подстраивается правильно, но при следующем нажатии окно открывается со стандартной шириной и высотой. Проверял ширину и высоту объекта перед созданием окна, они остаются правильные, в чём проблема?

```
  $('#Photo .img-block').click(function(){
     var href = GetText($(this).find('.img-inner').css('background-image'))[1];

     var img = new Image();     
     img.src = href;
     window.open(href, '', 'resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,fullscreen=no,scrollbars=no,dependent=no,width='+img.width+',left=500,height='+img.height+',top=100');

     return false; 
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного переработал Ваш код, пожалуйста посмотрите.

Функция, принимает селектор элемента, создаёт картинку и возвращает обратно ширину, высоту и ссылку картинки:

```
function getBgSize($element, callback) {
  $('<img />')
    .on("load", function() {
      callback(this.width, this.height, this.src);
    })
    .attr('src', $element.css('background-image').match(/^url\("?(.+?)"?\)$/)[1]);
};
```

Функция для открытия нового окна:

```
function openPopup(width, height, src) {
  var setttings = 'resizable=no, status=no, location=no, toolbar=no, menubar=no, fullscreen=no, scrollbars=no, dependent=no, width=' + width + ', left=500, height=' + height + ',top=100';

  window.open(src, '', setttings);
}
```

Пример использования функции:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Photo .img-block ').click(function() {
    getBgSize($(event.target), function(width, height, src) {
      openPopup(width,height, src);
    });
  });

  return false;
});
```

Весь код на [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/apavlovs/7brm5e6r/)!

Comment: Всё отлично работает, но в таком виде браузер блокирует всплывающее окно, как то это можно исправить?

Comment: Обновил код. Открытие нового окна вынесено в отдельную функцию, что бы современные браузеры не сочли это рекламным попапом и не блокировали. Так должно работать.

Answer (score 1):

Оптимизировал вызов, чтобы браузер не запрашивал разрешения на всплывающие окна:

```
$('#Photo .img-block').click(function () {
    var w, h, s;
    getBgSize($(event.target), function (width, height, src) {
        w = width;
        h = height;
        s = src;
    });
    var imgop = setInterval(function () {
        if ((w == h == s) != undefined) {
            window.open(s, '', 'resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,fullscreen=no,scrollbars=no,dependent=no,width=' + w + ',left=500,height=' + h + ',top=100');
            clearInterval(imgop);
        }
    }, 100)
    return false;
});
```